# Can't access header 'Content-Length' in Fetch API, CORS request in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, cors, http-headers

I'm making a Web Scraper extension for Chrome, I have to access some information cross domain. I'm setting the request mode to CORS but I still can't access 'Content-Length': it returns null even though it's not. 
By Googling and reading MDN's website I read [here](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-response-header-name) that 'Content-Length' is allowed in CORS requests but it doesn't appear to be so, at least in Google Chrome. I am 100% sure that the header is provided by the server: I checked with Chrome's DevTools Network tab and it shows it.

Just to make it **very clear**, I **CANNOT** change anything in the back-end.

Is there anything I can do to access that header? If I can't do anything about this, can anyone please explain me why the HTTP header 'Content-Length' is forbidden in Chrome CORS request?

For my extension I wrapped the Fetch API like so:

```
/**
 * Utility wrapper function for the 'fetch()' API, allows automatic retry upon
 * any error occurring during the request. It will trigger a given callback or waits
 * a specified amount of time before re-executing the function (4000 milliseconds
 * by default) whenever 'fetch()' throws an exception or returns an error state.
 * @param input 'fetch' API argument.
 * @param init 'fetch' API argument.
 * @param timeout Upon error, milliseconds to wait before retrying.
 */
const $fetch = async (input, init, onerror, timeout) => {
  try {
    const response = await window.fetch(input, init);
    if (response.status >= 400) {
      await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, timeout));
      if (onerror) {
        return await onerror();
      } else {
        init.cache = 'no-cache';
        return await $fetch(input, init, onerror, timeout);
      }
    } else {
      return response;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, timeout));
    if (onerror) {
      return await onerror();
    } else {
      init.cache = 'no-cache';
      return await $fetch(input, init, onerror, timeout);
    }
  }
};
```

Then I call the wrapped Fetch:

```
const response = await /* wrapped fetch */ $fetch(video.source, {  // 'video.source' is a url for an external CDN.
  mode: 'cors'
});
console.log(response.headers.get('Content-Length') || response.headers.get('content-length'));  // null
// I'm consuming the response as a ReadableStream
const reader = response.body.getReader();
const pump = async () => {
  const { done, value } = await reader.read();
  if (!done) {
    let blob = new Blob([value]);
    // ...
    await pump();
  }
  else {
    // ...
  }
};
await pump();
```

Comment: Are you making the request from a content script?

Comment: Yes, would it be any different if tried from the background script?

Comment: Responses don't always have `Content-length:`. It's not sent if the response uses "chunked" encoding.

Comment: Why do you need it, why can't you just get the `.length` property of the response?

Comment: Does this only happen when you do cross-origin requests? If not, I don't see how CORS is relevant.

Comment: Here's an example HEAD request:
```Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: keep-alive
Content-disposition: attachment
Content-Length: 367130940
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Server: nginx/1.11.5```

Comment: Modern Chrome disallows cross-origin requests in a content script. You need to do it in your background script as shown in the [official CORB explainer](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches)'s section 2 (and optionally use extension messaging to relay the data between the content script and the background script).

Comment: Property 'length' does not exist on type 'Response' @Barmar

Comment: Isn't it something like `response.text().then(text => text.length)`?

Comment: @Barmar unfortunately no, I can't store the whole file in memory at once since I'm accessing big files

Comment: I think it's being stored whether you use it or not. The browser has to store it when it gets the reply, because it doesn't know whether you're going to call `request.text()` or not.

Comment: No it doesn't Fetch is not the same as XHR.

Comment: @Fr3ddyDev If you do handle the entire response, even in a piece-by-piece way, you could add up `value.length` or `blob.size` for every `pump` iteration and get the full response size.

Comment: @apsillers unfortunately I can't, I wanted to know the size of the file before downloading to display progress.

Comment: @wOxxOm I tried in the background script and I still can't access Content-Length

Comment: Can't help without trying the extension myself. I can't be even sure you declared the background script properly.